# SSH to a server, having multiple domains, how to get domain?

Tags: ssh, domain, openssh

I have a server that is bound to multiple domains. Inside the server, I'd like to welcome the user to the domain he used to access the server.

How do I find out the [FQDN](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fully-Qualified_Host_Name) using scripting?

I have tried to have a sshd-configuration per domain, but I don't like to copy the sshd-configuration every time a new domain is bound to the server.

Answer (score 0):

You don't.

Well, there may be ways you might be able to accomplish something similar.  I will discuss those options, but first let's look at how protocols typically operate.

I recommend understanding how things work, and what protocols do, before dreaming up a lot of behaviors and then thinking they are desirable.  I once did that, thinking I could be creative and then invest some work into customizing things.  I later learned more about networking, and found it can be plenty challenging even without extra-challenging creative requirements.

Here are some common behaviors:

When you use an SSH client to connect to the host name, the SSH client starts by doing a DNS lookup.  This eventually provides the SSH client with an AAAA record (which gives an IPv6 address) or an A record (which provides an IPv4 address).  Then the SSH client uses an Internet protocol to communicate with the specified numeric Internet address.  The SSH server receives a connection from that numeric Internet address.

In contrast, HTTP connections follow that same process, but then the HTTP protocol specifies that the HTTP client uses the established TCP connection to transmit the desired URL.  At that point, HTTP servers receives the intended domain name.

Similarly, SMTP involves the client specifying an E-Mail address, allowing an SMTP server to receive the intended domain name.

SSH doesn't necessarily do this.

**Alternative One**
You can have SSH work different based on what SSH key a person uses.  If you distribute different SSH keys to people using different domains, you could have an effect along those lines.

**Alternative Two**
If you have multiple Internet addresses, you could simply have a different domain for each Internet address.  This is often feasible with IPv6.  With IPv4, having multiple public numeric addresses can be a bit more challenging/costly.

Comment: To 1: The keys are already distributed, I have to wait until the keys are out-of-date. To 2: This is a very good option but its not dynamic, i must configure every new domain.

Comment: What about ports, can I configure a Service Resource Records (SRV) to use a different port? I know, it may not dynamically.

Comment: @PeterRader , I assume you mean SRV resource records in DNS.  As far as I know, most protocols including SSH ignore those.  Sorry.  But you can run SSH on multiple TCP ports.  (One way may be to run multiple instances/copies of the server.  With fancy routing, you could even do that on multiple machines.)  The biggest downside is the clients would need to manually specify the TCP port.  If you control both the server and the clients (or can get cooperation from the clients), that's likely not a big deal.  That road may be worth pursuing.

Comment: @PeterRader I'd also say that there's no reason why DNS couldn't be used to check a DNS record, and to have a machine (which runs the SSH client) do something (like use the specified port numbert).  I was simply saying that I'm not aware of a standard, readily supported by commonly distributed pre-built software.  (Then again, the latest OpenSSH versions may have many customizations, including some I may not be familiar with.)  With heavy customization including using your own variation of source code, the technique of using a DNS record like SRV does sound technically feasible.

Comment: SSH is not listed in this list of protocols that commonly use SRV: [Wikipedia's article on "SRV record": section titled "Usage"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SRV_record#Usage)

Comment: Commonly, i found https://gist.github.com/taylor/1372925